# Spring Boot SecurityConfig class inconsistent

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to implement Spring-Boot-Security in my Spring Boot app following tutorial 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

I created a class and i wanted to override configure method in this class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

but Eclipse red-underline SecurityConfig and display this error:

```
The hierarchy of the type SecurityConfig is inconsistent
```

There are my Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried to update maven project, restart Eclipse but it didn't work.

Edit:

Helped change starter-security-version to 1.5.0 and starter-parent version to 1.5.1 there are strange error, but now it works :)

Comment: Are you inheriting from boot parent pom.

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent> yes i did

Comment: Did you tried to override a few method from parent class?

Comment: when i copied the code from tutorial it displays me "The method configure(HttpSecurity) of type SecurityConfig must override or implement a supertype method" like it do not read the extended class